# ListView is not scrolling inside NestedScrollView in android

Tags: android, listview

I've inflated a fragment from view pager which uses the listview. And list view does not support setNestedScrollingEnabled in pre lollipop devices. So I've added the listview inside a NestedScrollView but when scrolling the list it does not scrolling.

```
 <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_item_view"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:isScrollContainer="true">

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:divider="@color/gray_stroke_color"
            android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_64dp"                >
        </ListView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone suggest me any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using RecyclerView instead of ListView

Comment: This is the last solution I know. But there are a large no. of list view in my project. So changing all of them is time consuming. So it will be great if anyone can help me with the list view.

Comment: You don't need scrollView over listView, because listview has own scrolling

Answer (score 6):

Try using

```
setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```

Comment: setNestedScrollingEnabled(true); is only working with the api level 21 or higher. I'm talking about the api level below 21.

Comment: In XML also `<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView android:fillViewport="true" />` and `<View android:nestedScrollingEnabled = "true" />`

Answer (score 5):

```java
yourtListViewName.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled() and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you would want to use a ListView inside a ScrollView if it will take up the entire height/width of it's parent.

I would suggest just using the ListView in the root layout of your fragment and eliminate the ScrollView.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@color/gray_stroke_color"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_64dp"/>

    </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Also, I would suggest using RecyclerView instead of ListView as it implements NestedScrollingChild.

But if you are set on having nested scroll views in your layout you need to understand that NestedScrollView is intended to work as parent or a child scroll view while list. Here is a good example of a scrollview containing 2 other scrollviews:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Also, I noticed that you are maybe using CoordinatorLayout because you are setting the layout behavior of your child views. If so, you only need to specify the 'app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"' for your main and only ScrollView: A ListView, RecyclerView or NestedScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

You have to intercept the touch event for smooth scrolling

```
outerScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                findViewById(R.id.inner_scroll).getParent()
                        .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                return false;
            }
        });

        innerScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

its work if add this code
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"

```
 <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/lvExp"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the XML file, while defining the ListView, kindly write,

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

It will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom NonScrollListView

**NonScrollListView.java**

```
public class NonScrollListView extends ListView {

public NonScrollListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();    
}
```

}

**customListView**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:overScrollMode="never"
android:scrollbars="none" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <!-- com.Example Changed with your Package name -->

    <com.Example.NonScrollListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_nonscroll_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </com.Example.NonScrollListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lv_nonscroll_list" >
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout></ScrollView>
```

**In Java File**

**Create a object of your customListview instead of ListView like :**
NonScrollListView non_scroll_list = (NonScrollListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_nonscroll_list);

Comment: Can you please explain how your code behaves ?

Comment: We creating custom nested scroll view and using in XML. try the code and tell me if works correctly or not!!